# connection error with tire/elasticsearch remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, elasticsearch, tire

I have installed a ubuntu 12.04 remote server with elasticsearch.

I have installed elasticsearch with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless -y
wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.20.6.deb
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-0.20.6.deb
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

I get with `sudo elasticsearch status`:

```
* ElasticSearch Server is running with pid 2483
```

My elasticsearch remote server is working fine:

```
ubuntu12@juan:~/Escritorio/myapp$ curl http:/111.111.111.111:9200
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Hogan, Harold \"Happy\"",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.20.6",
    "snapshot_build" : false
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

or with my subdomain:

```
ubuntu12@juan:~/Escritorio/myapp$ curl http://elasticsearchserver.mydomain.com:9200
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Hogan, Harold \"Happy\"",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.20.6",
    "snapshot_build" : false
  },
 "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I can restart, start and stop elasticsearhc server.

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
 * Stopping ElasticSearch Server                                                                                                                                                                      [ OK ] 
 * Starting ElasticSearch Server                                                                                                                                                                      [ OK ]
```

I have a `tire.rb` file in `config/initializer/` folder with the next code:

```
if Rails.env == 'production'
  Tire.configure do
    url "http://elasticsearchserver.mydomain.com:9200"
  end
end
```

This is my capistrano task to reindex:

```
after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:elasticsearch:index_classes"
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :elasticsearch do
   desc 'run elasticsearch indexing via tire'
    task :index_classes do
      run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle exec rake environment tire:import CLASS=Object FORCE=true "
    end
  end
 end
```

I'm using mongodb as database, so I have not make migrations before reindexing.

This is capistrano error:

```
2013-04-06 14:25:50 executing `deploy:elasticsearch:index_classes'
 #
 #
 ** [out :: 111.111.111.111] Skipping index creation, cannot connect to Elasticsearch
 ** [out :: 111.111.111.111] 
 ** [out :: 111.111.111.111] (The original exception was: #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)>)
 ** [out :: 111.111.111.111] 
 ** [out :: 111.111.111.111] [IMPORT] Deleting index 'cvs'
 ** [out :: 111.111.111.111] 
 ** [out :: 111.111.111.111] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 111.111.111.111] Connection refused - connect(2)
 ** [out :: 111.111.111.111]
 #
 #
```

I have uploaded to production server the tire.rb file and I have tried:

```
bundle exec rake environment tire:import CLASS=Object FORCE=true
```

and I get the same result:

```
Skipping index creation, cannot connect to Elasticsearch
(The original exception was: #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)>)
[IMPORT] Deleting index objects'
rake aborted!
Connection refused - connect(2)
```

**What am I doing wrong? How can I fix connection between tire/rails app and my elasticsearch server?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just had the syntax wrong in your config/initializers/tire.rb, 
see below

```
Tire.configure do
  url "http://localhost:9200"
  #you can uncomment the next line if you want to see the elasticsearch queries in their own seperate log
  #logger "#{Rails.root}/log/es.log" 
end
```

Comment: I have added the syntax that it's working fine for me inside of  `tire.rb ` file. Thank you

Comment: Just a note for other readers of this post, the syntax is wrong. It should be url "http...." With no equals.

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax that it's working fine for me inside of `tire.rb` file

```
require 'tire'
Tire.configure { url "http://myremoteserver.com:9200" }
```

and now it's working fine!

Thank you!